# Apache HttpClient 5.2 - charset is added by default

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-5.x

It seems like Apache HttpClient adds a charset to the outgoing request whenever it sees fit.

When I set an header like `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, the request is ultimately sent with `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`.

I have searched everywhere but the behaviour is neither documented, nor does anyone seem to have the same problem: I have to send the header exactly like it is, without the charset.

Can somebody give me some pointers on how to disable the automatic charset adding?